# android phone as  server?

Tags: android, performance, web-applications, webserver

I want to host a web server on phone ,but is it good idea ? 
I have to consider about the limited amount of memory , battery etc . Any ideas on how to
tackle these issues ? If so , what type of web servers can be used ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: and by virtual server you mean server, right?

Comment: Yes , i have changed the question .

Comment: This type of question is trying to solicit opinion without your clearly stating the problem domain. In other words, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry , may be i am not clear .I want to implement web -application architecture on ANdroid. So i am looking into running node.js and using SS JS to talk to backend . I am worried that running a server might be costly . Any suggestions ????

Answer (score 5):

It is *possible* but only a good idea in unusual circumstances

- Most mobile networks are not set up for inbound traffic, so you'd need to be on wifi sourced from something that was (or service lan-local clients)
- Without rooting, you cannot open traditional ports for major services, but only unprivileged higher number ports
- android is not really designed to keep something always running without user interaction; you can use a boot complete receiver, and wakelocks and it may generally work but it's not what the platform was designed to insure.  Or with root you can modify the startup files and run command-line programs without ever starting the android runtime.
- You'd almost certainly want a power supply
- You can buy a comparable embedded arm platform more suited to this use for less than a reliable source of android phones would run, something like a beagle-board variant with wired ethernet.

Comment: +1 - so many better ways to do this (for the same or less money)

Comment: Thanks atleast i have an idea :)